# How to display remaining days and hours in django from DateTimeField?

Tags: django, django-views, python-datetime

Here I have a simple function for sending leave request and accepting by the admin.This code works for now but I want to add some feature here.For example if the user enter  `day = 2` which is `IntegerField` then it get stores into databse then after the leave has been accepted by the function below `def accept_leave(request,pk):` I want to display the remaining days of leave`(Example:1 day 12 hours and 30 sec. remaining to complete leave ).`After 2 days completed it should display some message like you leave has been completed.

I got no idea for starting this .How can I do it ?Any help would be great.

Is there any mistake in my approach ?

**EDIT:** Now I removed the day(Integer Field) and added start_day and end_day as DateTimeField. Now how can I display the remaining days and time of leave after the leave is accepted ?

models.py

```
class Leave(models.Model):
    staff = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='staff_leave')
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='staff_leave')
    sub = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    msg = models.TextField()
    start_day = models.DateTimeField()
    end_day = models.DateTimeField()
    #day = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_rejected = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sent_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py

```
def send_leave_request(request):
    form = MakeLeaveForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MakeLeaveForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            leave_days = form.cleaned_data['day']
            org = form.cleaned_data['organization']
            start_day = form.cleaned_data['start_day']
            end_day = form.cleaned_data['end_day']
            diff = end_day - start_day
            leave_days = diff.days
            print('org',org)
            if leave_days > request.user.staff.organization.max_leave_days:
                messages.error(request,'Sorry can not be sent.Your leave days is greater than {}.'.format(request.user.staff.organization.max_leave_days))
                return redirect('organization:view_leaves')
            else:
                leave = form.save(commit=False)
                leave.staff = request.user
                leave.organization = org
                leave.save()
                return redirect('organization:view_leaves')
    return render(request,'organization/send_leaves.html',{'form':form})

def accept_leave(request,pk):
    leave = get_object_or_404(Leave, pk=pk)
    leave.is_accepted = True
    leave.is_rejected = False
    leave.day = ? 
    leave.save()
    return redirect('organization:leave_detail',leave.pk)
```

Comment: Instead of storing the count of days, why don't you store the current date + count of days as a datetime?

Comment: should i change my field type for day in `Leave` model

Answer (score 2):

For your leave request, why don't you store something like :
start_date and end_date

The idea is (ideally) to store only things you can't compute.

Then you can make a [python property](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#properties) that computes the number of days between start_date and end_date (a "fget" would be enough for the property). A python property won't be stored in your database but it's not a big deal because you can compute it ! So you don't have to store it.

```
days = property(fget=_get_days, doc="type: Integer")
```

That means whenever the "days" attribute of an object "Leave" is accessed, the function "_get_days" is called to retrieve what you want.

If `self` represents a Leave object and you do `print(self.days)` it will print the result of `_get_days` finally.

The "doc" part is just here to indicate your property returns an Integer. It is not mandatory but a good practice in order not to forget it.

Then you must write that method "_get_days" (it must be above your property definition or Python won't know what is "_get_days"

```
def _get_days(self):
    return self.end_date - self.start_date

(something like that, that you convert into an int somehow)
```

Moreover, for your additional functionality, you must know how much leaves your user can have. Just store that on the user, on your user team or whatever you want.
Then to check if the user has remaining leaves he can take, just browse a queryset with all his accepted leaves and use the property mentioned above.
Then you substract the result to the total number of leaves the user can take.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Now I removed the Integer field day and added start_day and end_day as DateTimeField. I will upvote this answer

Comment: Because I wanted to display remaining leave in a time also.For eg. `1 day 1 hr. 30 sec remaining`